# Combining Case Statements in a View

Tags: sql

I have these two case statements and can not for the life of me figure out how to combine them to show in a MSSQL view. Any help would be great.

```
CASE WHEN [ordertype] = '2' THEN [CommissionAmt1] * - 1 ELSE [CommissionAmt1] END
```

and

```
CASE WHEN (is_member('Buyer') = 1 OR is_member('CustomerService') = 1) THEN 0 ELSE CommissionAmt1 END
```

Comment: Can you explain in simple english, with what logic you want to combine these two case statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding the first case to wherever the CommissionAmt1 is referenced in the second statement.

```
CASE WHEN (is_member('Buyer') = 1 OR is_member('CustomerService') = 1) THEN 
    0 
ELSE 
    CASE WHEN [ordertype] = '2' THEN 
      [CommissionAmt1] * - 1 
    ELSE 
      [CommissionAmt1] 
    END
 END
```

Or going the other way. It was hard to understand which way the calculation needs to be performed. The only hint was []

```
CASE WHEN [ordertype] = '2' THEN 
    (
        CASE WHEN (is_member('Buyer') = 1 OR is_member('CustomerService') = 1) THEN 
            0 
        ELSE 
            CommissionAmt1 
        END
    ) * - 1
ELSE
    CASE WHEN (is_member('Buyer') = 1 OR is_member('CustomerService') = 1) THEN 
        0 
    ELSE 
        CommissionAmt1
    END
END
```

Either way, you would be able to save some calculations by sub querying the dependent value.

```
SELECT
    *,
    ValueWithDependant=CASE WHEN (Dependant>0) THEN (SomeValue / Dependant) ELSE NULL END
FROM
(
    SELECT
       X,Y,Z,   
       Dependant=CASE WHEN SomeValue=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM
       SomeTable
)AS DETAIL
```